# No route matches [GET] "/order_items" when adding an item to shopping cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Whenever I try to add an article to the shopping cart from the item's show page I've been getting the following routing error: **ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/order_items")**. When checking on the console, no item has been added to the shopping cart.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'articles#index'

  resources :articles, except: [:destroy]
  resources :order_items, only: [:create]
  resources :orders do
    get '/current', to: 'orders#current', on: :collection
    resources :checkout, only: [:create]
  end
end
```

**order_item.rb**

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :article
end
```

**rails routes**

```
order_items POST   /order_items(.:format)  order_items#create
```

**order_items_controller.rb**

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    order_item = current_order.order_items.new(article_id: params[:article_id])
    if order_item.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Successfully added to cart.'
    else
      redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Error adding to cart.'
    end
  end

  def current_order
    order = Order.where(user_id: current_user.id, status: 'created').order(updated_at: :desc).last
    order || Order.create(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to 'Add to cart', order_items_path(article_id: params[:id]), method: :post %>
<% else  %>
   <%= link_to 'Log In', new_user_session_path , class: "text-blue-500" %>
<% end  %>
```

Comment: Use `<%= button_to 'Add to cart', order_items_path(article_id: params[:id]), method: :post %>` instead. This creates an actual form element which is better for accessibility and works even without JS. If you really want to use a link you need to use `data: { turbo_method: :post }` in Rails 7.

Answer (score 0):

As to why? You are only creating the route

`resources :order_items, only: [:create]`

so you only get the POST route. You are asking for the GET route. Thus your error. As pointed out `button_to` would work. The reason your `link_to` form is not working is it attempts to retrieve the `order_items` path before making it a POST request. The `button_to` defaults to a POST verb unless told otherwise.

Comment: If this was Rails 6 AND Rails UJS was working properly it should still send a POST request. Usually one of those two things are wrong.